# Is it possible to apply a filter to a data validation drop down list?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a drop down list on a that shows a consolidated parts library from another worksheet. This worksheet is constantly going to be updated until we can get a working database so the way the parts list functions is more or less set in stone.

The parts library is bought over using a query and looks like this:
[image]

I have concatenated some of the data to form a named table `ProjectTab and looks like this:
[image]

The named table forms a detailed data validation list which looks like this:
[image]

In order for the worksheet to auto-fill I shortened the output of the data validation list to only output the `Part Index` which looks like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

On Error Resume Next

Dim textVal As String
Dim strVal As String

    strVal = Target.Value
        If Target.Column = 2 Then
            textVal = Left(strVal, 9)
                Target.Value = textVal

    End If
End Sub
```

The following `IF` statement allows me to figure out what Type of product the part is
`=IF(B2>0,IF(LEFT(D2,1)="1","Assembly",IF(LEFT(D2,1)="2","Sub-Assembly",IF(LEFT(D2,1)="3","Software",IF(LEFT(D2,1)="4","Hardware",IF(LEFT(D2,1)="5","Chemical",IF(LEFT(D2,1)="6","Spare",IF(LEFT(D2,1)="7","Spare",IF(LEFT(D2,1)="8","Document",IF(LEFT(D2,1)="9","Misc",""))))))))),"")`
Which produces the following column:
[image]

I would like to use something similar to the above `IF` statement to filter the drop down list to select the parts i.e. I preselect the `Assembly Type` via a filter at the top of the work sheet which in-turn filters the `Part List` drop down list to the respective type.

Is this possible? If so how could I go about doing this?

Thanks,

Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

I've written a VBA example that I think will work for you. You can download a sample [here](http://hubbyclub.com/misc/VBA_DataValidationList.xlsm), but if preferred and for future readers, you can build your own worksheet based on my example below.

For this example, you'll want to set up your workbook as follows.

[image: First Sheet]

[image: Second Sheet]

[image: Third Sheet]

Copy and paste this into the "Example" Worksheet Code.

```
    Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim AssemblyFilter As Range, PartsDropDown As Range
    Dim strList As String, strAssemblyFilter As String
    Dim i As Long

    Set AssemblyFilter = Range("B1") 'Set this to the cell that has the Assembly Filter
    strAssemblyFilter = AssemblyFilter.Value

    If Not Intersect(Target, AssemblyFilter) Is Nothing Then 'Only Run following code when Assembly Filter cell has changed
        strList = ""
        With Sheets("Parts Library")    'Sheet with Parts Library
            For i = 1 To .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
                If strAssemblyFilter = .Cells(i, "B").Value Then    'Compare Assembly Filter to values in Column "B"
                    strList = strList & "," & .Cells(i, "A").Value  'If filter matches, then append this to the data Validation List
                End If
            Next i
            strList = Mid(strList, 2)   'Chop off leading comma
        End With

        'Apply Data Validation to this Range (starting at cell B4 and ending at the last row with data in column A)
        Set PartsDropDown = Range("B4:B" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        With PartsDropDown.Validation
            .Delete
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
            xlBetween, Formula1:=strList                  'Pass in Validation List created above
            .IgnoreBlank = True
            .InCellDropdown = True
            .InputTitle = ""
            .ErrorTitle = ""
            .InputMessage = ""
            .ErrorMessage = ""
            .ShowInput = True
            .ShowError = True
        End With
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

When you change the Assembly Filter and the `Worksheet_Change` event fires, the code first generates the Parts List based on the Assembly Filter, it then resets and creates a new Validation filter starting at B4 and ending at the last row with data in Column A. You can adjust this as needed, or even hard code a range if preferred.

Hope this helps and let me know if you have any trouble modifying this for your use.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out now!

Comment: This is a good answer to my question but doesn't quite solve it. With the data validation source being set up at a formula it sets up an auto updating table e.g. if the able had 20 possible entries and I had selected row 10 but needed to add a new entry at row 9, my previous selected entry will be budged into row 11 but the selected entry will still show entry 10. I hope this makes sense? 
Unfortunately the spreadsheet will constantly be updated over time so I do not have the luxury of static data :(

Comment: @DanM, I've updated my answer with a solution that uses VBA. Hope this helps.

Comment: this is a brilliant work around and I cannot find any flaws. Thank you so much for putting your time and effort into this answer